# Pandas complex condition with last and previous values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

There is a table with order numbers (Pandas Dataframe)

```
>>> ord = pd.DataFrame([[241147,'01.01.2016'], [241148,'01.01.2016']], columns=['order_id','created'])
>>> ord
    order_id    created
0   241147  01.01.2016
1   241148  01.01.2016
```

There is a history of changes in order statuses

```
>>> ord_status_history['ord_id','osh_id','osh_created','osh_status_id','osh_status_reason']

    ord_id  osh_id  osh_id_created  osh_status_id   osh_status_reason
0   241147  124632  01.01.2016  1   None
1   241147  124682  02.01.2016  2   None
2   241147  124719  03.01.2016  10   None
7   241148  124633  01.01.2016  1   None
8   241148  126181  06.01.2016  5   Test_reason
```

I want to add to the table ord the information on the last order status and the penultimate status of the order (the order is determined by the field 'osh_created').

```
order_id    created Last_status_id  Last_status_date    Prev_status_id  Prev_status_date    reason
0   241147  01.01.2016  10  03.01.2016  9   02.01.2016  NaN
1   241148  01.01.2016  5   06.01.2016  1   01.01.2016  Test Reason
```

But I do not understand how to use np.where or loc condition. Since for one order in ord_status_history a few lines, but I need to select only one for every order.

I try to do smth this (But its' very bad):

```
for i in range(ord_stat['order_id'].count()-1):
    if (ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id']==ord_stat.loc[i+1,'order_id']):
        if (ord_stat.loc[i,'osh_id_created']<=ord_stat.loc[i+1,'osh_id_created']):
            if (ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Last_status_date']=='NAN'):
                ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Prev_status_date']=ord_stat.loc[i,'osh_id_created']
                ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Last_status_date']=ord_stat.loc[i+1,'osh_id_created']
            else: 
                ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Prev_status_date']=ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Last_status_date']
                ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Last_status_date']=ord_stat.loc[i+1,'osh_id_created']
        else:
            if (ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Last_status_date']=='NAN'):
                ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Prev_status_date']=ord_stat.loc[i+1,'osh_id_created']
                ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Last_status_date']=ord_stat.loc[i,'osh_id_created']
            else: 
                ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Prev_status_date']=ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Last_status_date']
                ord.loc[ord_stat.loc[i,'order_id'],'Last_status_date']=ord_stat.loc[i,'osh_id_created']
```

Read about nlargest, but I don't understand how I can take status_id, if I use 'osh_created' with nlargest

```
ord_stat.groupby('order_id')['osh_id_created'].nlargest(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have the following DataFrames:

```
In [291]: ord
Out[291]:
   order_id    created
0    241147 2016-01-01
1    241148 2016-01-01

In [292]: hst
Out[292]:
   ord_id  osh_id osh_id_created  osh_status_id osh_status_reason
0  241147  124632     2016-01-01              1              None
1  241147  124682     2016-02-01              2              None
2  241147  124719     2016-03-01             10              None
7  241148  124633     2016-01-01              1              None
8  241148  126181     2016-06-01              5       Test_reason
```

we can aggregate it as follows:

```
In [293]: funcs = {
     ...:     'osh_status_id':{
     ...:         'Last_status_id':'last',
     ...:         'Prev_status_id':lambda x: x.shift().iloc[-1]
     ...:     },
     ...:     'osh_id_created':{
     ...:         'Last_status_date':'last',
     ...:         'Prev_status_date':lambda x: x.shift().iloc[-1]
     ...:     }
     ...: }
     ...:

In [294]: x = (hst.sort_values('osh_id_created')
     ...:         .groupby('ord_id')['osh_status_id','osh_id_created']
     ...:         .agg(funcs)
     ...: )
     ...:
```

resulting in

```
In [295]: x
Out[295]:
        Last_status_id  Prev_status_id Last_status_date Prev_status_date
ord_id
241147              10               2       2016-03-01       2016-02-01
241148               5               1       2016-06-01       2016-01-01
```

now we can merge it back to the original `ord` DF:

```
In [296]: ord.set_index('order_id').join(x).reset_index()
Out[296]:
   order_id    created  Last_status_id  Prev_status_id Last_status_date Prev_status_date
0    241147 2016-01-01              10               2       2016-03-01       2016-02-01
1    241148 2016-01-01               5               1       2016-06-01       2016-01-01
```

or using `merge()` method:

```
In [297]: pd.merge(ord, x, left_on='order_id', right_index=True)
Out[297]:
   order_id    created  Last_status_id  Prev_status_id Last_status_date Prev_status_date
0    241147 2016-01-01              10               2       2016-03-01       2016-02-01
1    241148 2016-01-01               5               1       2016-06-01       2016-01-01
```